# Duplicate entry error in my Android app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This error occurs when I sync the gradle file

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.class

I tried cleaning the project, rebuilding the project and multidex, excluding the  module.

My min sdk is 19. If greater than 20, multidex worked properly, 
but in SDK 19 it didn't work.

This is my gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig 
    {
        applicationId "com.example.prototype_01"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes 
    {
        release 
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies 
{
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
  compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.1'
  //compile files('libs/android-core-3.2.1.jar')
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
  compile 'com.tsengvn:Typekit:1.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What can be done to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to Multidex.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.class

It means that you are adding the same class `CameraConfigurationUtils.class` **twice**.

Check your jar files.
If you have `libs/android-core-3.2.1.jar` you are adding twice the same class.
This class is inside the [jar](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera) and inside the [library](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/tree/master/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera) compile `'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'`.

**Remove the jar file from the libs folder.**

Answer (score 0):

> duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/

You've added too many libraries. Try removing one at a time until your app can build.

Start with removing any conflicting Jar files from libs related to Zxing

Zxing core  is not necessary, the embedded one already compiles it

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
// compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

Multidex / changing your SDK version isn't going to magically fix overlapping dependencies